# How to automate import functionality in Magento?

Tags: magento, import, cron, job-scheduling

We are using Magento as our eCommerce platform. We have Oracle apps in which we store our Customer,Price, Product etc. details.

Our requirement is that , we have so many customer groups & each customer is having different prices for products. So for that we have develop module for tier pricing. Now we want to automate this functionality as instead of manually uploading data/csv files , we want automatic data import in Magento?

So one option for us is to use CRON job...so that we can daily take data from Oracle...We have connection to Oracle  db through PHP...SO can anybody guide me regarding how I start?
Or is there any other approach for the same? Or any readily available extension specifically for AUTOMATIC import for Magento with external system?

Or In simple term, we need whatever Magento' existing manual IMPORT functionality in AUTOMATED way???
plz help...

**What We are thinking that We have conection to both Mysql & Oracle database throgh php...So we will fetch data from Oracle db & insert in into Magento's Mysql db....If we create such .php file & insted of manually importing data in Magento, can we set CRON job & include this php file in that so that say for every 24 hrs data from Oracle will get fetch & inser into Mysql/Magento?

Is i possible to do the same??

apart from extension any other suggestion plz...**

Comment: We have same procedure but we choosen Oracle Siebel and developed a module ( COD - Customer Order and Delivery ) which is many customers has special prices based on different brands. I wonder that, if you have more than 100 customer groups, what will you do then?

Comment: Hi, I have the same functionality to be done. I found your question and wanted to know how did you fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are using [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpwebsite/magmi/) to perform daily imports of our data.

We currently have 30+ customer groups and this will be growing as time goes on, Magmi seems to be able to handle it without any issue.

The process for our import is:

1. Retrieve product data from our backend system
2. Determine what has changed from the previous day
3. Upload a csv file holding the changes to the server
4. Kick off the Magmi import

If you could automate the first 3 steps, then you could always put the 4th on a cron job.

Comment: I just want to add that Magmi is super fast and can be triggered from command line, so it really seems to be the way to go

Comment: HI, my doubt is how exactly Magmi automate import functionality?

Comment: You can call Magmi via command line see the [Magmi CLI page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpwebsite/magmi/magmi-command-line) for details. I'd set up a cron job to do this.

Comment: Can we use Magmi for Magento EE 1.10.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Magento Enterprise feature:

> Scheduled Import/Export (based on csv files)

Alternatives:

- Create an extension that uses Magento's import/export functionality (not the data flow - runs very slow)
- Buy an extension that covers this functionality (search in Magento Connect, etc)

Comment: HI FlorinelChis, We are using Magento EE(1.10.0.1). How can we do Scheduled Import/Export....Our data is in Oracle db that we want to automatically import(say for every 8 hours or so) in Magento...

Comment: You need a script running on the Oracle database to generate the csv file for Magento. If you want the sample file that Magento needs just add a few products and use Import/Export Export function to get that list... the import uses the same file format.